# Создание консольной команды artisan

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь создать команду с помощью этого мануала https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-artisan-commands-to-manage-database-records-in-laravel. По нему все работает хорошо. Я ввожу созданную команду, ввожу ссылку, описание и все это сохраняется в базу.

Сейчас я работаю с redmine api. Мне нужно получить оттуда трудозатраты и с помощью созданной консольной команды загрузить данные из redmine в базу.

Но не совсем понимаю как это сделать. Вот мой код:

**Model Time Entry**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $project
 * @property int $issue
 * @property string $activity
 * @property string $comments
 * @property int $hours
 * @property int $month
 * @property int $year
 */
class TimeEntry extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];
}
```

**Commands/LinkNew** (Здесь я получаю исключение `Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar::Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\{closure}("2022-08-21 08:26:13", "updated_at")`)

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\TimeEntry;
use App\Services\RedmineAPIService;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class LinkNew extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'link:new';
    protected $description = 'Create a New Link';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $redmineService = new RedmineAPIService();
        $users = $redmineService->getUsersInfo();

        //isset($user);
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $id = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);
            $project = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);
            $activity = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);
            $issue = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);
            $comments = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);


            if ($this->confirm('Is this information correct?')) {
                $link = new TimeEntry();
                $link->id = $id;
                $link->project = $project;
                $link->activity = $activity;
                $link->issue = $issue;
                $link->comments = $comments;
                $link->save();

                $this->info("Saved.");
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

**RedmineAPIService**

```
    public function getTimeEntriesInfo(int $user_id): array
    {
        $users = self::getAllData('time_entry', ['user_id'=>$user_id]);
        return $users['time_entries'];
    }
```

И вот вопрос, как расписать функцию `handle()`. В моем примере данные `id, project, activity, issue, comments` я получаю с помощью функции `getTimeEntriesInfo()`, которая расписана в `RedmineAPIService`.

**UPD:**

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $redmineService = new RedmineAPIService();
        $users = $redmineService->getUsersInfo();

        foreach ($users as $user) {             
            $data = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);

            $id = $data['id'];
            $project = $data['id'];
            $activity = $data['id'];
            $issue = $data['id'];
            $comments = $data['id'];

            if ($this->confirm('Is this information correct?')) {
                $link = new TimeEntry();
                $link->id = $id;
                $link->project = $project;
                $link->activity = $activity;
                $link->issue = $issue;
                $link->comments = $comments;
              //  dd($link->getAttributes());
                $link->save();

                $this->info("Saved.");
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

**dd($link->getAttributes());**

```
249 => array:10 [
    "id" => 5369
    "project" => array:2 [ …2]
    "issue" => array:1 [ …1]
    "user" => array:2 [ …2]
    "activity" => array:2 [ …2]
    "hours" => 1.0
    "comments" => "Комментарий"
    "spent_on" => "2022-05-27"
    "created_on" => "2022-05-27T05:00:19Z"
    "updated_on" => "2022-05-27T05:00:19Z"
  ]
```

Comment: Исключение явно не в команде или не в этом месте ошибки. Класс команды мало чем отличается от класса контроллера, вместо реквеста Вы получаете параметры, дальше делаете что и как хотите.

Comment: Вы по стеку исключения прошлись? Где и как оно появляется? Так же, какая схема у таблицы для TimeEntry модели?

Comment: Попробовал вывести ```dd($link->getAttributes());``` перед строчкой ```$link->save();```. Получил именно те данные, которые пытаюсь сохранить. Как я понял ```$data``` нужно каким-то образом перебрать (см. UDP), но я не совсем понимаю как. Добавил изменения в ```UPD```.